# Uninstalling pygame on linux

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying to uninstall pygame, but i'm not sure how and i couldn't find any resources to help me.
I had installed pygame with the command `python3 -m pip install -U pygame -- user`, and attempted to uninstall it with `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python-pygame`, but it spat back `Package 'python-pygame' is not installed, so not removed`. but, in the terminal, I can do `python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens` and the aliens game will show up.

edit: please note that i am new to linux and am running galliumos

Comment: You seem to think that `-U` uninstalls a module, but it doesn't. It updates it. However, seeing the message "... is not installed, so not removed" means it is not installed. Is pygame in the output of `python3 -m pip freeze`?

Comment: Just to be clear, "`so not removed`" is in the error message is because -U attempts to uninstall the installed version of the package and **then install** the newest version. So even if you wouldn't have received that error, you'd have ended up with pygame installed.

Comment: To uninstall using `pip` use `pip uninstall ...`

Comment: It's possible that pygame is installed "globally", so you can try to uninstall it using your distro's package manager

Comment: I had made several errors when asking my question, and have attempted to edit it to better say what i did.

Comment: Why are you using `apt-get`? Just use `python3 -m pip uninstall pygame --user`

Comment: I agree, if you install with `pip` then uninstall with `pip`. And similarly, if you install with `apt` then uninstall with `apt`.  I was reading about pip in linux and learned that it is highly recommended to install python packages with apt and avoid pip if you can

Comment: `python3 -m pip uninstall pygame --user` worked

Answer (score 0):

PyGame can be uninstalled with the command

```
python3 -m pip uninstall pygame --user
```

Answer (score -1):

pip uninstall packagename works fine

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325383/how-to-uninstall-pygame-from-ubuntu

found it in footnotes

Comment: Try to be more concise with your words for other people who will find this answer and need to use it :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31753029)