# How to uninstall a package on linux using pip3?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to uninstall package "pygame" using pip3 on linux, the commands I've tried so far:

```
pip3 uninstall pygame
python3 -m pip uninstall pygame
```

The output I am getting in both cases:

> Found existing installation: pygame 1.9.6

> Not uninstalling pygame at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr

> Can't uninstall 'pygame'. No files were found to uninstall.

The 2nd command was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411041/uninstalling-pygame-on-linux) with the option --user but the output I am getting in this case is that there is "no such option: --user".

Comment: Did you check existence of the module which you're trying to delete. You can  use `pip3 freeze`  to check installed modules.

Comment: Yes, the module definitely exists, pygame version 1.9.6 is listed in the output of pip3 freeze (also the output of the commands I am trying to use to uninstall it states that an existing installation is found).

Comment: How did you install pygame? You will need to uninstall using the same process as you installed pygame with. My hunch is you did `sudo pip install pygame` or some variant involving sudo.and pip.

Comment: I've installed it just as you described it - in that case, I should be able to uninstall it with the commands I listed above. @Dunes

Comment: `sudo pip uninstall pygame` should work then. For future reference, using `sudo` in combination with `pip` is almost always the wrong thing to do. Try looking into setting up and using virtual environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you installed `pygame` with `sudo pip install pygame` or some other variant involving sudo and pip. In general you should avoid doing this. This is because you are modifying the your OS' internal python installation. It might bring in versions of libraries that are incompatible with various internal python scripts that your OS uses. And if you uninstall something, you might unintentionally remove a library that is still needed by your OS.

If, and only if, you installed pygame in this manner then you can uninstall with:

```
sudo pip uninstall pygame
```

In future, it is better to create and use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) to manage installing libraries for your own projects. Example:

```sh
# Use your distro's package manager to install venv, if it is not already installed.
# apt is aware of your OS' system requirements in a way that pip is not, and so will not
# break things in the way that pip might.
sudo apt install python3-venv

python3 -m venv venv --prompt myproject
. venv/bin/activate
# in this shell, pip and python will now refer to the versions installed in your
# virtual environment (complete with any additional python packages you 
# have installed -- only pip initially)

# setuptools and wheel are not installed by default, and may be needed to install
# some python packages
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

Comment: As I mentioned before, this solution doesn't work, I explicitly wrote that in my question. Executing this command with sudo privilages changes absolutely nothing (it's not the issue of privileges I think, it says that "Can't uninstall 'pygame'. No files were found to uninstall." - I don't know what files are missing and why are there missing). Also I am pretty sure I didn't use "sudo pip install pygame" for installing the package, I simply used "pip install pygame"

Comment: "As I mentioned before...", I don't think what you've written tallies with what you think you've written. You wrote that you used `pip uninstall ...` which will do something different to `sudo pip uninstall ...`. The output of your previous attempt states it found pygame in a directory that is owned by root and reserved for the OS (`Not uninstalling pygame at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`) . So if `apt` cannot find `pygame` then it would seem likely you ran `sudo pip install pygame`. What is the output of `apt list --installed | grep pygame`?

Comment: The output of aforementioned command is "python3-pygame/groovy,now 1.9.6+dfsg-3 amd64 [installed]"

Comment: Right, so what happens when you try `sudo apt remove python3-pygame` then (as opposed to just `python-pygame` -- without the 3)?

Comment: This solution - `sudo apt remove python3-pygame` - worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall python-pygame

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pygame
```

Uninstall python-pygame and it's dependent packages

```
sudo apt-get autoremove python-pygame
```

Purging python-pygame

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pygame
```

To delete configuration and/or data files of python-pygame and it's dependencies from Ubuntu Xenial then execute:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge python-pygame
```

for more details check this [link](https://howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/python-pygame?action=remove)

Comment: The thing is I don't have python-pygame package installed at all so none of the commands listed above do anything. pygame==1.9.6 shows however in the output of pip3 freeze and is located in the "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages" directory (output of the pip3 show pygame).